# SVD to find the common factors

Tags: time-series, factor-analysis, linear-algebra, svd

Let's say I have a time series $R\in \mathbb{R}^{T\times M}$ where $T$ shows the dates and $M$ is the number of variables. I do an SVD on it and obtain $R=U\Sigma V^\top$, where $U\in \mathbb{R}^{T\times K}$, $\Sigma\in \mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$, $V\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times K}$ and $K=\min\,(T,M)$. Now if I want to obtain the $P$ common factors from this decomposition I will have dimensions $U_p\in \mathbb{R}^{T\times P}$, $\Sigma_p\in \mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$, $V_p\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times P}$ and $P\leq K$. My question is which of these variables shows the $P$ common factors time series? Is it $U_p$, $V_p$ or $U_p\Sigma_p V_p^\top$?

I got myself confused since if we take $P=5$ and $M=100$, then $U_p\Sigma_p V_p^\top$ has dimensions $T\times 100$. How do I look into these $5$ factors when I end up with $100$ time series?